# Which Linux distribution is used for running servers with a hypervisor?

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, distribution-choice

I just bought my first dedicated server for home use. Since I've never had a server at home I'm not sure which operating system is the standard for running multiple VMs on the bare metal with a hypervisor.

I've heard about centOS being used for similar purposes, but since I'm a Ubuntu user are there any disadvantages to using Ubuntu as the host system?

Also, if  I was to pick Ubuntu, should I install Ubuntu-core for minimal footprint or should I go with Ubuntu-server?

Comment: Welcome to Unix&Linux. Try to ask different questions separately, and while related, not blending several questions together. Pretty much any Linux distro, the kernel is the same, some have pre-packaged solutions that are more tightly integrated than the others. Google is your friend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sure that it is possible to use Ubuntu for your purposes. However, I can't say that I've tried it.

If you're keen to stick with the Debian family, but flexible about Ubuntu, [Proxmox](http://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Installation) looks like a popular option. You can choose between installing a specialized ISO or installing onto Debian Jessie.

My impression is that the virtualization tools in the Fedora/Redhat/CentOS family are pretty strong. If that appeals, then [oVirt](https://www.ovirt.org/documentation/quickstart/quickstart-guide/) is worth a try.

Comment: RH and SuSE also are investing in OpenStack out-of-the-box ; xen can also be an interesting toy. +1 for mentioning Proxmox and oVirt.

Answer (score 1):

Ovit in my opinion is not very suitable for use at home. Its architecture is more suitable for enterprises which use a lot of servers.Its big and complicate.

You should also remember that for management Ovirt purposes you have to select one dedicated virtual machine.

I can not say anything about Proxmox, because i have not worked with it.

Why do not you use https://virt-manager.org/. It is simple and fast.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of your question - use Ubuntu as you are familiar with it. Go with Ubuntu server. And don't lie to yourself, there is a possibility that you will be changing it. Anyway if you are starting and you already know something go for it.

For starters I would simply use virt-manager with libvirt. Easy to configure, quite simple and for home usage should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is VMware vSphere Hypervisor for Free....

https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/evalcenter?p=free-esxi6

Answer (score 0):

Go ahead with Ubuntu without any hesitations. I have been doing all sort of virtualization and stuff in Ubuntu. Everything works well.