# Virtual Lab on a server. What hypervisor? Proxmox, OpenStack, ESXi?

Tags: xen, openstack, proxmox

**I would like to run a virtual lab to show a piece of software - imagine 10 students, each using 3 VMs** (somehow students shouldn't be able to touch each other's machines).
It's going to be a small factor server that has fake raid. **I'm going to need mdadm** - Intel says use mdadm for Intel RSTe fake raids.
**I am in the process of choosing what hypervisor** (if that's correctly termed) to install. **I'd like a decent UI, preferable web-based, I won't shy away from ssh. mdadm support too.**

My options so far:

I have some experience with **ProxMox**. I like it, the stuff missing from the UI i can do myself - create fake adapters to simulate NAT and to segregate machines with multiple network adapters. mdadm might be difficult to install - there are tutorials, but it's not officially supported.

I have tried **ESXi**, but I don't find it easy to use. It's not a normal linux. The UI is pretty, but I couldn't manage to import a Windows machine - neither from OVA/OVF, nor even a .vmware image - it needs to convert them, which makes no sense. It also cannot use mdadm, or if it can it will be very, very difficult.

**XEN** i've heard doesn't have a control panel, instead I have to install its windows client on one of the machines.

**OpenStack** is another software I'm considering. I'm trying to run DevStack to evaluate, but it's not going well. I've heard good things about it, and from what I've heard it's like AWS and suits my requirements fine. But I've been told it's quite complex and better suits a company with multiple servers, not a single machine. It contains multiple pieces (nova, keystone, glance, neutron ...) and it might not be easy to handle. I don't know about mdadm, but since it runs on multiple distributions, it might be doable.

I don't know about other options.
**Any comments?**

Comment: A similar question came up the other day. oVirt is one option missing from your list, though I don't know about mdadm support. [http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/319022/which-linux-distribution-is-used-for-running-servers-with-a-hypervisor/319042#319042]()